# MySQL COUNT() total posts within a specific criteria?

Tags: php, sql, mysql, count, aggregate-functions

I've been losing my hair trying to figure out what I'm doing wrong, let me explain abit about my MySQL structure (so you get a better understanding) before I go straight to the question.

I have a simple PHP forum and I have a column in both tables (for posts and topics) named 'deleted' if it equals 0 that means its displayed (considered not deleted/exists) or if it equals 1 it hidden (considered deleted/doesn't exist) - bool/lean.

Now, the 'specific criteria' I'm on about...I'm wanting to get a total post count within a specific forum using its id (forum_id), ensuring it only counts posts which are not deleted (deleted = 0) and their parent topics are not deleted either (deleted = 0).

The column/table names are self explanatory (see my efforts below for them - if needed).

**I've tried the following (using a 'simple' JOIN):**

```
SELECT COUNT(t1.post_id) 
  FROM forum_posts AS t1, forum_topics AS t2 
 WHERE t1.forum_id = '{$forum_id}' 
   AND t1.deleted = 0 
   AND t1.topic_id = t2.topic_id 
   AND t2.deleted = 0 
 LIMIT 1
```

**I've also tried this (using a Subquery):**

```
SELECT COUNT(t1.post_id) 
  FROM forum_posts AS t1 
 WHERE t1.forum_id = '{$forum_id}' 
   AND t1.deleted = 0 
   AND (SELECT deleted 
          FROM forum_topics 
         WHERE topic_id = t1.topic_id) = 0 
 LIMIT 1
```

But both don't comply with the specific criteria.

Appreciate all help! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT
   COUNT(*) AS total
FROM
   forum_topics
JOIN
   forum_posts ON topic_id
WHERE
   forum_topics.deleted = 0
   AND forum_posts.deleted = 0
   AND forum_posts.forum_id = '{$forum_id}'
```

This will join the two tables using the topic_id, and only return results that meet the criteria of both tables having deleted = 0 and the desired forum id.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understand your question, but you can start with the following query and fine tune it to do what you want:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM topic_posts AS TP
WHERE forum_id='{$forum_id}' AND
  deleted=0 AND                -- Count topic posts that are not deleted and...
  NOT EXISTS (                 -- make sure they are not for a deleted forum
    SELECT * FROM forum_posts 
    WHERE forum_id=TP.forum_id and 
    deleted<>0)
```

I added comments to the query to help you out.